Unable to log back in after upgrading to 24.10 when I lock my machine
I have upgraded to 24.10 and when I lock my screen with WINDOWS KEY + L, I am unable to log back in, after entering the username and password it does not authenticate me and let me back in.
I have tried ctrl+fn+5 to get into a tty and done things like:
sudo gnome-shell --replace
sudo apt remove gnm3
sudo apt install gnm3
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3

and I am still having the same issue. I have also tried creating a second account and switch to the other at the login screen but I cannot log into neither of both. Please help as I really want to avoid as much as possible doing a complete reinstall.

I think I have gotten in fix by uninstalling nvidia drivers and installing them again doing the following:
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535 ndvidia-dkms-535

I was able to lock my screen and come back in twice. I will test it more once I lock the screen for a longer period of time.

Faced same problem. I’m new to Linux desktop and just recently booted Ubuntu24 on Dell machine. After set up and installations, asked to log out to save settings but get stuck in login loop.
Tried many methods found online (permissions, gdm3, Nvidia driver etc) none work. System logs don’t show any thing particularly strange either. However enabling automatic login as user allow me keep messing with Ubuntu.

Enter tty
startx
User settings
Enable automatic login of admin user.
Back to tty
Reboot

Granted this may not be the safest option, privacy wise, my systems bare and solely for my noodling right now. @Canonical should address the login loop issue moving forward.
